# German words options for English equivalent of "workout" such as "Übung"

Tags: english-to-german

I want to best communicate "Enjoy your workout."

So far I have

```
Genießen Sie Ihre Übung
```

But it sounds a bit generic and the word seems to mean more along the lines of "exercise". Which is not necessarily fitness related.

Comment: z. B. `Genießen Sie das Training`

Comment: Workout is one of the words that has "almost" made it to the german language; you won't find it in a "serious" book, but lifestyle magazines use it all the time. So depending on your audience you don't even have to translate it. See http://www.fitforfun.de/workout for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language purists would probably translate it as

> Trimm-Dich-Einheit

or simply

> Trimmeinheit.

The most common analogy in German is the word itself:

> Workout

or combined with other words conveying the phasing meaning

> Workout-Einheit, Workout-Session, …

The problem is, that the concept of a workout was created, when the German language simply absorbed English vocabulary without adopting it. And it needs adopting, as the concept of `to work out` doesn't suit the German view of sports as [Turnen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turners). The words `trainieren` and `üben` (with their derivatives `Training` and `Übung`) suit the German view on sports better, but don't suit `workout`.

The best analogies are probably `Sport machen` and `ins Gym gehen`, which unfortunately don't build suitable derivatives. So, you should get creative (if appropriate) and say

> Genießen Sie Ihren Sport. / Genießen Sie den Sport.

or

> Genießen Sie Ihre Zeit bei uns.

Comment: I am a little confused about why you say that the "German view of sports" is Turnen. The link that you provided mentions that those gyms were "were not only athletic, but also political."

The context that I had in mind for use here, was just in casual conversation like if we are about to go to lift weights for a short amount of time. But less of the social aspect that is normal at most gyms.

Comment: @JGallardo You are right. But this "Turnen" also influenced the language used to talk about sports and consequently the view on sports itself. So, a simple "workout" without that philosophical/political background is hard to translate, because all German terms convey or at least connotate some philosophical/political meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, Toscho's translations are correct.

However, the wording with "genießen" sounds a bit stiff at least to my ears. A more colloquial way of phrasing the same idea is

> **Viel Spaß** beim Workout!

Comment: I think, the OP's question was about the translation of `workout`, not of `Enjoy`.

Comment: No argument there. :)